# Function that consumes two lists and produces a list of all second elements

Tags: list, recursion, racket

In Dr. Racket, how would I write a function that consumes 2 lists (and each list contains 2 list elements (the first is a string, the second is a number)) and produces a list of all the second elements?

If this problem is hard to understand, here is an example:

```
(second-separator 
      (list (list "JG" 851) (list "Gh" 90)) 
      (list (list "hb" 34) (list "vc" 45) (list "kl" 462)))
```

Should Produce:

```
(list 851 90 34 45 462)
```

Here is my code so far:

```
(define (second-separator los1 los2)
  (cond
    [(and (empty? los1) (empty? los2)) empty]
    [(empty? los1) (cons (second (first los2)) 
                         (second-separator los1 (rest los2)))] 
    [(empty? los2) (cons (second (first los1)) 
                         (second-separator (rest los1) los2))]
    [else (list (second (first los1)) 
                (second (first los2)) 
                (second-separator (rest los1) (rest los2)))]))
```

My code works properly for all cases except for the `else` case.

If I plug in the example given above, I end up getting

```
(list 851 34 (list 90 45 (list 462)))
```

instead of

```
(list 851 90 34 45 462)
```

How would I correct this problem? Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[else (list (second (first los1)) 
            (second (first los2)) 
            (second-separator (rest los1) (rest los2)))]))
```

This is where you are getting the nested lists specifically. `(list element_1 element_2 ... (recursive call which generates a list)` is particularly dubious and often leads to nested lists because it ends up expanding to something like this:

```
(list elem_1 elem_2 ... (list elem ...))
```

What you are looking for to generate a "flat" list is either:

```
(cons elem_1 (cons elem_2 ... (recursive call))
```

(semantically: "link" `elem_2` to the list that `recursive call` generates then "link" `elem_1` to the list that generates etc..)

or

```
(append (list elem_1 elem_2 ...) (recursive call))
```

(symantically: append the list of `elem_1`, `elem_2`, etc... to the list `recursive call` generates)

Answer (score 0):

Re-written in a pattern-matching pseudocode to make it more visually apparent, with equations corresponding to the `cond` cases, your code becomes

```
second-separator []  []             =  []
second-separator []  [[a,b], ...n]  =  [b, ...second-separator [] n]
second-separator [[a,b], ...n]  []  =  [b, ...second-separator n []]
second-separator [[a1,b1], ...n1] 
                 [[a2,b2], ...n2]   =  [b1, b2, second-separator n1 n2]
```

which explains the output you're getting. For the output you describe, it must be:

```
second-separator []  []              =  []
second-separator []  n2              =  _______________
second-separator [[a,b], ...n1]  n2  =  [b, ...second-separator n1 n2]
```

(the most important equation is the last; fill in the blanks).